# Can we get direction from google maps for android programatically?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there any exposed Intents from Google Maps app for Android that allow the developer to know what is exactly being shown on the screen: Current street, next direction, speed etc…

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such Intent according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). If there were, it would be a security hole, I think.